# Recursive MergeSort to optimize space

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

For my assignment I've been tasked with implementing a merge sort that uses a temp array half the size of the original array. I'm having a hard time understanding how to get this working. It works sometimes but certain values will throw it out of place. Any help or direction on this would be helpful. Heres my current code right now:

```
public void sort(T[] items) {

    // Your sort should work without allocating any more memory than this...
    T[] temp = (T[]) new Comparable[(items.length + 1) / 2];
    mergesort(items, temp, 0, items.length - 1);

}
private void mergesort(T[] items, T[] temp, int left, int right) {
    if (left == right) {
        return; // Region has one record
    }

    int mid = ((right + left)) / 2; // Select midpoint  
    mergesort(items, temp, left, mid); // Mergesort first half
    mergesort(items, temp, mid + 1, right);
    merge(items,temp,left,mid,right);
}

/**
 * Merge two sorted sub-arrays.
 */
private void merge(T[] items, T[] temp, int left, int mid, int right) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        if (count == temp.length) {
            break;
        }
        temp[count] = items[i];// Copy subarray to temp
        count++;
    }

    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = mid + 1;
    for (int curr = left; curr <= right; curr++) {
        if (i1 >= mid) { // Left subarray exhausted
            items[curr] = items[i2++];
        } else if (i2 > right) { // Right subarray exhausted
            items[curr] = temp[i1++];
        } else if (temp[i1].compareTo(items[i2]) <= 0) {
            items[curr] = temp[i1++];
        } else { // value
            items[curr] = items[i2++];
        }
    }

}
```